# How do I read port configuration for my Spray Can?

Tags: scala, port, spray

I'm trying to set up a basic Spray Can server. In the code, I see this:

```
IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(service, interface = "localhost", port = 8080)
```

I'd like to have that port (8080) be configured from the application.conf file. However, the format of the conf file (http://spray.io/documentation/1.2-M8/spray-can/configuration/) does not have a port defined.

Does this mean the way to accomplish this is to define a port configuration myself, and read it from application.conf? And if so, how is this done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to add a port setting to `application.conf` and load it manually, like this.

```
import com.typesafe.config._
val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
val serverPort = conf.getInt("port")
IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(service, interface = "localhost", port = serverPort)
```

where src/main/resources/application.conf looks like this:

```
port = 8090
```